# Interrupts in PIC16F84A

Tags: assembly, pic

I am coding a program for PIC16F84A in assembly,
When an interrupt A occurs and the interrupt routine of A begins the GIE gets set to 0,
if while we are in the A interrupt subroutine another interrupt B is triggered the program will continue in A's subroutine because GIE is not enabled (won't jump to 0x04), but since the Enable of B is set will the flag of B get set anyway? 
So do I need to make sure that all flags are set back to 0 before RETFIE or only reset A's flag to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When an interrupt A occurs and the interrupt routine of A begins the
>   GIE gets set to 0, if while we are in the A interrupt subroutine
>   another interrupt B is triggered the program will continue in A's
>   subroutine because GIE is not enabled

Why are you turning GIE off in the interrupt handler?
An interrupt will not interrupt an interrupt handler.  Interrupt B handler will start when you return from interrupt handler A

Comment: GIE bit gets automatically set to 0 by the hardware to avoid having an interrupt interrupting another interrupt's subroutine by jumping to 0x4,
what I want to know is "can B's flag get set while I'm in A's subroutine with GIE being 0 because B's enable is set? even though GIE=0?" maybe that makes it clearer

Comment: Yeah B's interrupt flag gets set, and that fires an interrupt as soon as A finishes

Comment: But if some event which causes an interrupt happens twice while A is running then you will miss one of the events